# Не могу разобрать массив

Tags: php, массивы

Как получить элемент `data:ProtocolNode:private`?

```
Array ( 
    [tag] => message 
    [attributeHash] => Array ( 
    [from] => 79хххххххх 
    [type] => text 
    [id] => 1BD86E5A275E631733D 
    [offline] => 0 
    [t] => 1454504944 
    [notify] => Ivan Ivan ) 
    [children] => Array ( 
                    [0] => ProtocolNode Object ( 
                    [tag:ProtocolNode:private] => enc 
                    [attributeHash:ProtocolNode:private] => Array ( 
                                                                [v] => 2 
                                                                [type] => pkmsg ) 
                    [children:ProtocolNode:private] => 
                    [data:ProtocolNode:private] => 3ڕ�����mu��1�r_�5s�W�+ynן�j!��lE�����n)hutӚ�o�����N� �4^"B3!c�]@�X/HE�x�T��A<8��S��2��RT "u��u�&Yܟn��\+�6���soW(є��0��h ) ) 
    [data] => )
```

Comment: a->{'data:ProtocolNode:private'} у вас вот это не получается?

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $array['children']['data:ProtocolNode:private'];

var_dump($array['children']['data:ProtocolNode:private']);
```